# Importing cstring fails: include <cstring> error

Tags: c++, c-strings

I'am working on a group project with ROS and C++ on Ubuntu 16.04. Everything is working fine until two weeks ago I got this error 
message out of the blue:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/cstring:42:0,
         from /usr/include/boost/math/special_functions/detail/fp_traits.hpp:23,
         from /usr/include/boost/math/special_functions/fpclassify.hpp:20,
         from /usr/include/boost/math/special_functions/round.hpp:16,
         from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/time.h:58,
         from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/ros.h:38,
         from /home/benjamin/Documents/bob_ws/src/tutorial/hello_world/src/hello_world.cpp:1:
/usr/include/string.h: In function ‘size_t strlen(const char*)’:
/usr/include/string.h:395:6: error: ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope
      cout << *__s;
      ^
/usr/include/string.h:395:6: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/time.h:54:0,
         from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/ros.h:38,
         from /home/benjamin/Documents/bob_ws/src/tutorial/hello_world/src/hello_world.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/iostream:61:18: note:   ‘std::cout’
   extern ostream cout;  /// Linked to standard output
          ^
In file included from /usr/include/features.h:367:0,
         from /usr/include/stdlib.h:24,
         from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/platform.h:53,
         from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/time.h:53,
         from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/ros.h:38,
         from /home/benjamin/Documents/bob_ws/src/tutorial/hello_world/src/hello_world.cpp:1:
/usr/include/string.h:396:6: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
      __THROW __attribute_pure__ __nonnull ((1));
```

As a newbie to C++ and ROS my first thought was that I messed up by installing / removing some packages. So I tried reinstalling the whole ros framework. Didn't work, so I wrote a little programs 
which (I think) shows what my problem is. I cannot include `<cstring>`:

```
#include <cstring>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  return 0;
}
```

When compiling that with `g++ -Wall a.cpp  -o atest` I got a [2500 row error message](https://pastebin.com/KXYeYg50).

Now I think there could be a little problem with cstring, but I have sadly no idea how to solve it. 
My googling suggests that `locate cstring | grep include` might be of interest:

```
/usr/include/boost/compatibility/cpp_c_headers/cstring
/usr/include/boost/python/docstring_options.hpp
/usr/include/boost/test/utils/basic_cstring
/usr/include/boost/test/utils/basic_cstring/basic_cstring.hpp
/usr/include/boost/test/utils/basic_cstring/basic_cstring_fwd.hpp
/usr/include/boost/test/utils/basic_cstring/bcs_char_traits.hpp
/usr/include/boost/test/utils/basic_cstring/compare.hpp
/usr/include/boost/test/utils/basic_cstring/io.hpp
/usr/include/c++/4.8/cstring
/usr/include/c++/5/cstring
/usr/include/qt4/Qt/q3cstring.h
/usr/include/qt4/Qt3Support/q3cstring.h
```

Maybe it is a problem that there are two versions of C++ installed?

I'am pretty close to setting my system up
from scratch so you guys are my last hope.

Comment: What gets returned from command - which g++

Comment: Those are very odd. Has your `/usr/include/string.h` been tampered with? The first error hints at an unclosed `extern ”C”` block. (The first error is always most important.)

Comment: A huge stacktrace I pasted to pastebin so this question remains readable. The link is: https://pastebin.com/KXYeYg50 @HassanVoyeau

Comment: @molbdnilo ls tells that the file has been changed in April. So I don't think it is tempered. How can I find this "extern 'C'" block?

Comment: @陳力 Could you specify your hint a little more please? where should this local-prefix point to? (I'am newb)

Comment: Sorry, I got something wrong

Comment: As mentioned, the `/usr/include/string.h` file seems broken. It should not include the `iostream` header. I’d be interested in the provenance of that file. If this file is old and your code worked before then the reason is probably that the file wasn’t actually included before because some other file was used instead.

Comment: @Belorenz Can you show the content of `/usr/include/string.h`. From the include trace you posted, it seems that string.h tries to include `/usr/include/c++/5/iostream`. If this is the case, then its probably not good beacause string.h is a strictly C standard header and it should not include any C++ headers.

Comment: @KonradRudolph this file is from april. last time everything was fine, was mid october. So this file is old and the code worked before. What do you suggest to find out if another file was used before?

Comment: @JulienVillemure-Fréchette pastebin is down right now, so  I used gist this time. Thats the /usr/include/string.h : https://gist.github.com/belorenz/617876eb39030dfc7a4af0f473f7a407 . You are right.  It tries to include iostream.

Comment: A wild guess is that "someone"  has tried to detect a problem involving `strlen` by printing its parameter (a "friend" of yours, perhaps?) The `#include` and the `cout` line should not be there.

Comment: Yup, that file is broken as suspected. This is actually somewhat of an issue regardless of your file. You probably need to completely remove and install your system’s (not a custom!) GCC installation.

Comment: @molbdnilo That might have happend, but I'am the only one using this computer and this code is not part of our repo or something. I sit together with a friend who is also part of this project and compare mine with files. His are working. I'am comparing the string.h and let you know the results.

Comment: Guys, I changed my string.h with the one from my friend and my little example above is working now. ``inlcude <cstream>`` is not a problem anymore. I can even build my ros project. thank you so much guys!

Comment: I'am still wondering how this could happen. Is it a good idea to write an answer in which I explain how i solved this problem or is it fine that I wrote it in comments here?

Comment: @Belorenz I would recommend you re-install the Ubuntu package with the C header files, `libc6-dev`, so you can be sure they're fine. (I would really recommend against editing system headers. In fact, I would recommend against sudo editing anything outside `/etc` unless you _really_ know exactly what you are doing.) Kudos to molbdnilo and Konrad Rudolph for catching on to this so quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @molbdnilo and @Konrad Rudolph I figured that somehow my `/usr/include/string.h` (which is a C Header file) tried to import `/usr/include/c++/5/iostream` (which is a c++ lib). 
After a vim diff with a working `string.h` I deleted the divergent lines wich was only the include statement for iostream.

As @digitalarbeiter recommended it is in general a bad idea to manualy change some code in this kind of files so I reinstalled `libc6-dev` with

`sudo apt-get install libc6-dev --reinstall`

and it still works.

I still have no idea how this could happen. The file was edited in april and the error occured in october. Anyway thanks to all the helpers!